# Mapping an enum T's values to valid flag values (0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24...)

Tags: c#, keyboard, mapping, bit-manipulation, enumeration

Lets say I have the following enum:

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
    A, // = 0
    B, // = 1
    C, // = 2
    D, // = 3
    E, // = 4
    ...
}
```

Basically, what I want to do is to map every value to valid mask value (0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128...), so that SomeEnum.A would be equivalent to 0, while SomeEnum.B to 1, SomeEnum.C to 2, **SomeEnum.D to 4, SomeEnum.E to 8 and so on**. I kinda got it working, but I'm facing another problem: the more values the given enum has, the bigger gets that mapping, probably resulting in a super ultra giant long long long long number.
Are there any known techniques for this?

Here is my code:

```
public class Flagger<T> where T : struct
    {
        private static Dictionary<int, ulong> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, ulong>();

        static Flagger()
        {
            int indexer = 0;

            // Since values can be duplicated, we use names instead
            foreach (String name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)))
            {
                ulong value = 1UL << indexer++; // 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16...

                Console.WriteLine("{0} generated value {1}", name, value);

                dictionary.Add(name.GetHashCode(), value); 
            }
        }

        private ulong flags;

        public void Add(T value)
        {
            // Create hash only once for both checkup and storation
            int hash = value.ToString().GetHashCode();

            if (Check(hash))
            {
                ulong flag = dictionary[hash];

                flags &= flag;
            }
        }

        public void Remove(T value)
        {
            // Create hash only once for both checkup and storation
            int hash = value.ToString().GetHashCode();

            if (Check(hash))
            {
                ulong flag = dictionary[hash];

                flags &= ~flag;
            }            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tests whether a value has already been added or not
        /// </summary>
        public bool Check(T value)
        {
            int hash = value.ToString().GetHashCode();

            return Check(hash);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Quick checkup because no hash needs to be computed
        /// </summary>
        private bool Check(int hash)
        {
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(hash))
            {
                ulong flag = dictionary[hash];

                return (flags & flag) == flag;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

The reason for all this is that I'm working with the System.Window.Input.Key enum and I'm not able to test whether some flags are enabled, for example:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

int vk = 0x55; // U
Key key = KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey(vk);

if ((Key.W & key) == key)
{
    Console.WriteLine("True!");
}
```

The above "if" condition returns me true, which is not really true!

Comment: Instead of asking why `Y` doesn't work for achieving `X`, you should explain 'X', i.e. what are you missing from `KeyInterop` ?

Comment: It looks like there is perfect answer to question as asked, but it is unlikely to help you achieve your goal whatever it is. You may want to ask new question starting with goal and showing what you tried/think is solution. Asking other way around frequently lead to [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I dont know why you guys are talking about that "XY" problem. I pretty much have specified whos X and Y, what I tried as well as the reason my approach seems to fail. Please take a look at my replies to Colin below. This should clear some things, hopefully!

Answer (score 1):

Use bit shifting:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    None   = 0,
    First  = 1 << 0,
    Second = 1 << 1,
    Third  = 1 << 2,
    Fourth = 1 << 3
}
```

EDIT: after clarification of the problem, this is how you'd go about evaluating if a flagged key enum value contains the equivalent value of a differently-typed, but similarly-named enum value.

```
[Flags]
public enum Keys1
{
    O = 0,
    K = 1,
    A = 1 << 1,
    Y = 1 << 2
}

public enum Keys2
{
    O,
    K,
    A,
    Y
}

public bool DoesIncludeKey(Keys1 keys1, Keys2 keys2)
{
    var keys1Names = keys1.ToString().Split(',');
    return keys1Names.Contains(keys2.ToString());
}

//ToString() on keysVals results in "O,K", 
//which is what makes the above function work.
var keysVals = Keys1.O | Keys1.K;

//true!
var includesK = DoesIncludeKey(keysVals, Keys2.K);
//false.
var includesA = DoesIncludeKey(keysVals, Keys2.A);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am not creating an enum, instead, I'm creating a wrapper for a given enum. Some enums dont have the [Flags] attribute specified, nor the values are 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16... If we deal with large enums, such as the one I have specified above, which has 200+ values, we would have: 1 << 200 (stored in the static dictionary), which is a really big number (a lot bigger than ulong) and that's my problem.

Comment: If you're running out of bits, I suppose you can't really do bitwise operations (including AND-ing). AND-ing hashes will certainly serve no purpose, at any rate. Can you explain the problem you're trying to solve in more depth. I understand you want to detect a 'U' button press, but I don't understand why/how that button press is coming in like a flagged enum. It might be worthwhile to re-think the approach.

Comment: You kinda got my point now (after your edit). The System.Windows.Input.Key enum does not have the flags attribute (the System.Windows.Forms.Keys does, though). The reason I just dont do an equality operation (=) is because I'm supposed to test it against multiple other keys, for example (imagine we have a flaggable enum): Key keystroke = Key.W | Key.S; Then, if I wanted to check whether this keystroke contains the S key, I would just do that: if ((keystroke & Key.S) == Key.S). There is no sort of enum that maps the virtual key codes into an mutually exclusive values.

Comment: @YvesHenri - I updated the answer. I think that's what you're looking for.